# Get entry by entry

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-ce

I have the following scenario:

Articles Table

```
id | description | supplierID
_____________________________
1  | Testarticle | 1
```

Supplier Table

```
id | description 
_______________________
1  | Example Industries
```

When reading out an article, for example
`SELECT * FROM articles WHERE ID=1`, i also need the supplier description in my result.

What would be an appropriate way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select a.id as ArticleID, a.description as ArticleDescription, a.SupplierID,
s.description as SupplierDescription
from articles a
inner join supplier s on a.supplierID = s.supplierID
where a.id = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to Join these two table

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    articles a
INNER JOIN Supplier b
ON a.SupplierID = b.id
WHERE   a.id = 1
```

Check out how [`INNER JOIN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) works.

Answer (score 1):

you need to join Both tables,

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    articles a
        INNER JOIN Supplier b
            ON a.SupplierID = b.ID
WHERE   a.ID = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0e9dd/3)

To learn more about joins, here's a great reference for it

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: @JW Wow, I didn't know anything about SQLFiddle. Do you create tables your own or SQLFiddle has a tool about it?

Comment: @SonerGönül SQLFiddle has a tool that converts text into DDL statement `:D`

Comment: @JW. Good to know. But in the "text to ddl" popup, you write first line columns with comma, and you write second line values with comma. Right? Is there any video about how we can use SQLFiddle?